# Text blurry after 3D transform

Tags: css, css-transforms

I have a div that I've rotated around the X-axis with perspective. The div contains text that gets blurry when the rotation is applied. Is there any way to get the text sharp on rotation around this axis? I've tried the translate3d and translateZ "hack" but without success.

```css
.tilt {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid #222;

    -webkit-transform: perspective(500px) rotateX(35deg);
       -moz-transform: perspective(500px) rotateX(35deg);
            transform: perspective(500px) rotateX(35deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="tilt">    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores deleniti expedita nostrum ipsam culpa rem earum recusandae saepe nulla repudiandae molestiae natus consectetur neque quasi quos laudantium doloribus iusto minima!
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita id magnam labore doloribus velit quidem exercitationem aspernatur nobis dolore omnis deserunt culpa quibusdam nemo adipisci possimus nesciunt debitis minus ullam!
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis commodi assumenda sed natus eligendi! Temporibus nobis molestiae aperiam ut repudiandae doloribus eveniet quod illo. Natus reiciendis eum ab itaque enim!
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet fuga recusandae quisquam voluptatibus qui ipsa pariatur dolor libero cumque quod iste error porro laborum. Non quam quidem tempora corporis veniam!</div>
```

Comment: it seems a common problem, look here http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/perspective/

Comment: I am looking at the Fiddle on 2 monitors, on OS/X. On my external monitor, it's indeed blurry - like most text actually on my external OS/X monitor, on the Macbook pro Retina monitor it's perfect.. look : http://snag.gy/pmJ1W.jpg

Comment: It seems to me the text gets *rendered* and then the entire rendered rectangle gets a perspective transform; the text itself does not get redrawn "in perspective". Hence, you get fatter pixels at the near end and aliasing artifacts in the center and at the far end.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here is a workaround to make the text less blurry. It doesn't make it pixel perfect but it is better. Tested on chrome 38 FF 32 and IE 11 windows 7.

The point is to scale the text up (x2) with `font-size` (in the example fiddle I also scaled the width/height of the container) and scale it back down with `transform: scale(0.5);`. The text is rendered with less blur than the 1:1 default scaling ratio.

Here is a screenshot (chrome 38) of both fiddles :

[image: Less blurry text with 3D transform]

And a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/3wxk6eun/11/)**

*CSS :*

```
.tilt {
    margin: -200px auto 0;
    width: 600px;
    height:800px;
    font-size:2em;
    border: 2px solid #222;


    -webkit-transform: perspective(500px) rotateX(35deg) scale(0.5);
       -moz-transform: perspective(500px) rotateX(35deg) scale(0.5);
            transform: perspective(500px) rotateX(35deg) scale(0.5);
}
```

---

**Scale ratio optimization :**

When the text has the default scale ratio, it is blured as we can see in the original OP [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3wxk6eun/). When you scale the text with a 0.1 ratio the text becomes aliased with pixel rendering bugs :

[image: Aliased text after 3d transform and a 0.1 scale ratio]

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/3wxk6eun/13/)**

The point is to find the best compromise between aliased and blured text. For the OP example, 0.5 gives a good result but I am sure it can be optimized.

---

As suggested by [John Grivas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26176557/text-blurry-after-3d-transform/26252137#comment-41197196), you can also add a 1px text-shadow that tends to make the middle and top lines render better :

```
text-shadow: 0 0 1px #101010;
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/3wxk6eun/14/)**

---

As commented by [Mary Melody](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26176557/text-blurry-after-3d-transform/26252137?noredirect=1#comment41267306_26252137), some fonts render better than others, you can check this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/yh6wkg20/1/)** with the most popular google fonts.

Comment: My friend you deserve it !.I was working two-three hours for that but I thought maybe there will be another approach so i didn't answer.This is actually a solution you adviced! And just to add if you want you can give a little shadow like that http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/fbxc4qLq/ . :)

Comment: I just said that this is a solution and I liked it. I said I tried the same but added an extra   text-shadow: 0 0 1px #101010; .Thats all and I upvoted.I want to support your answer!

Comment: Of course you can. If I come up with another thought I will tell your.But you answered first and you have to win here!

Comment: @web-tiki +0001) What about using a different font family? (IMO that looks good) - http://jsfiddle.net/yh6wkg20/

Comment: @MaryMelody thx. Yes, that looks nice, seems some fonts render better than others : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/yh6wkg20/1/

Comment: Note increasing font-size by higher `n` such as 10 and scaling it back by 10 doesn't produce clearer graphics - because now `scale(0.1)`'s is not good at scaling a small value and becomes the new source of blurriness itself. So 2x size then scale(0.5) works well.

Answer (score 0):

I find out that best solution for all workers is to use full width of window for text element and after this scale element down to size which you want. It working for me in safari also in chrome and it's not blury on any stage.

I find right scale for full hd resolution and after this I just recomputing it.

```
 const screenWidth = window.innerWidth;
 const scale = 0.00155 * (1920 / screenWidth);
```

You can use this scale for css transfrom scale and it should work.