# How to achieve performant transitions without blurring text in Webkit due to hardware acceleration

Tags: css

I have an absolutely positioned element which I am transitioning into the viewport. The element has text within it. My understanding is as such:

- It's bad practice to apply transitions to an element's position (i.e. top, left, bottom, right, margin, padding). Doing so forces the browser to re-flow heavily as the element moves across the page.
- It's good practice to apply transforms to an element as the browser does not incur re-flow as the box model location stays in the original position.
- Applying a transform to an element in the Webkit browser forces hardware acceleration. (Or can be forced to do so, i.e. if transform: translateX does not then you can use translate3d with z-axis being 0).
- Text which is hardware accelerated is not treated as vector. This causes the text to become blurry.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26176557/text-blurry-after-3d-transform) article discussing workarounds, but I'm not satisfied.

It seems like it would be better to transition the element with transforms, but, once the element has reached its resting state, replace the transform with left/top of the same measure to remove the element from hardware acceleration.

Am I on the right track? Is there an easier solution here?

As a simple example, check out the text when toggling the will-change property. You can see that the text blurs in anticipation of a transform occurring even though no transform is taking place. This is the same thing as leaving a transform on the element even after it has finished moving / having the text next to an element which is moving. It would be really nice to tell Chrome to keep the text as a vector, but I suspect all parent elements get promoted which is why the text gets changed.

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('.example').toggleClass('is-blurred');
});
```

```css
.example {
  font-size: 24px;
}
.example.is-blurred {
  will-change: transform;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Toggle blur</button>

<div class='example'>
  I am some text
</div>
```

Comment: Take a look at the [will-change](https://dev.opera.com/articles/css-will-change-property/) property

Comment: I'm aware of the will-change property and have experimented with it heavily. The will-change property gives the browser a heads-up that it should take the steps necessary to hardware accelerate. So, instead of the text being blurry during a transition, it's blurry as long as will-change is applied to it, as well. I'm looking for essentially the inverse of will-change, but I don't know if that exists.

Answer (score 0):

When CSS transition is finished, browser don't need a lot of hardware resources to keep element in place. So don't worry about it.

Comment: What I mean is that if the initial state is transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); and its final state is transform: translate3d(100px, 100px, 0); then when it enters its final state the browser still keeps the element hardware accelerated so text is blurry.