# CSS hexagons - text inside is blurry with webkit-backface-visibility:hidden

Tags: css, webkit, css-shapes, css-transforms

I have a hexagon grid, and I've used `-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden` to smooth out the edges in Chrome. But, this makes the text inside it blurry.

**[See demo](https://jsfiddle.net/78L8erb8/)**

So I tried moving the text out of the backface element and instead absolutely positioned it on top. This fixed the blurriness, but created a new problem. Each hex shape is a link. Once I moved the link out of the child element, the links overlap the preceding hex shape in the interlocking grid.

**[See demo 2](https://jsfiddle.net/j62d7997/2/)**

See how when you scroll over the right side of the first hex, you get the link for Hex 2 because it overlaps it.

Is there a way to have smooth hex edges AND clear text AND not overlap the links?

Comment: This might help : [Responsive grid of hexagons](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26116497/1811992) the technique used to make the hexagon grid is different and the text seems less blurry than in your examples.

Comment: Thanks. I checked out the example, but I still see a noticeable difference in clarity when I add/remove backface hidden from their hex as well.

Comment: I am not aware of a pixel perfect solution to this but I found a workaround to make it less blurry and described it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26252137/1811992)

Comment: I am actually seeing the correct link on each part of the hexagons, I am using chrome 45

Comment: That's strange, @Saar. I'm using Chrome 45 too. Roll over the right side of the first hex... does it highlight the second hex when you get close to the right side?

Comment: @Lindsay yup, now the issue is reproduced. before it didn't happen though 100%